# CollectionAssert.Contains() as a replacement for NUnit's Assert.Contains()

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I'm replacing NUnit with TestManager in my Visual Studio project.  NUnit has the following Asserts:

- `Assert.Contains(string, collection)`
- `Assert.That(collection, Has.No.Member(string))`

I'm using the following for TestManager:

- `CollectionAssert.Contains(collection, string)`
- `CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain(collection, string)`

I'm looking for a way to replace

`Assert.IsEmpty(collection)` and `Assert.IsNotEmpty(collection)`

I could use `CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain(collection, new List<string>())`  But would rather have something more solid reflecting on collection.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't simply use `.IsTrue()`, e.g: `Assert.IsTrue(collection.Count > 0)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ usually is good for checking collections.

```
 Assert.IsFalse(collection.Any()); //      Assert.IsEmpty(collection) 
 Assert.IsTrue(collection.Any()); //      Assert.IsNotEmpty(collection)
```

If you are looking for more fluent interface - consider [FluentAssertions NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions).

```
collection.Should().BeEmpty("because there are no doors");
```

Comment: Linq is the answer.  Thanks!